# get full information about constraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I want to create query that result like this :

```
column_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
```

I have try something like this

```
SELECT col.column_name, cons.constraint_name, cons.constraint_type,col.referenced_table_name, col.referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints cons, information_schema.key_column_usage col
WHERE col.table_name = 'countries'
AND cons.constraint_name = col.constraint_name
AND cons.table_name = col.table_name
```

but, I get wrong column_name...  :(

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`, `CONSTRAINT_NAME`, `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`, `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = 'countries'
AND `CONSTRAINT_NAME` <> 'PRIMARY';
```

I don't know about `constraint_type`. I haven't found this column in information_schema.

Comment: constraint_type is like (PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY, UNIQUE, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys always have name 'PRIMARY', foreign keys always have referenced_table_name, so you can get that info from one table - `key_column_usage`:

```
SELECT
  column_name,
  constraint_name,
  CASE
    WHEN constraint_name = 'PRIMARY' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
    WHEN referenced_table_name IS NULL THEN 'UNIQUE KEY'
    ELSE 'FOREIGN KEY'
  END constraint_type,
  referenced_table_name,
  referenced_column_name
FROM
  information_schema.key_column_usage;
```